# How to get key value from elastic beanstalk environment variables

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I need to use Amazon elastic beanstalk environment variable values for a local development but don't want them hard coded when I do a code push.

I'd like to run a bash script to set the variables, and this is how I do it with Heroku:

```
echo "... SETTING DATABASE_URL" 
export DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL)
```

With elastic beanstalk, I can get a list of env variables with:

```
eb printenv <name of environment>
```

I've tried grepping for just the value, e.g.

```
eb printenv my-environment | grep DB_NAME
```

... but that returns entire line and I just need value. So tried grepping with regex and it won't return anything, .e.g.

```
eb printenv my-environment | grep '/(?s)(?<=DB_NAME).+/'
```

It's a simple regex query and checks out fine on regex101.com, so not sure what the problem could be.

Any ideas of how to get specific key values pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
# eb printenv | grep RAILS_ENV
     RAILS_ENV = production

# eb printenv | grep RAILS_ENV | awk '{print $3}'
production
```

So in you case it would be

```
DATABASE_URL=$(eb printenv | grep DATABASE_URL | awk '{print $3}')
```